# Tensorflow unpooling after max_pool_with_argmax using indices

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

While trying to implement U-SegNet from the paper by Google, I've got a problem implementing unpooling operation using argmax indices.

The full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def unpool(pool, ind, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], name=None):
    with tf.variable_scope('name') as scope:
        input_shape = tf.shape(pool)
        output_shape = [input_shape[0], input_shape[1] * ksize[1], input_shape[2] * ksize[2], input_shape[3]]

        flat_input_size = tf.cumprod(input_shape)[-1]
        flat_output_shape = tf.stack([output_shape[0], output_shape[1] * output_shape[2] * output_shape[3]])

        pool_ = tf.reshape(pool, tf.stack([flat_input_size]))
        batch_range = tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.cast(output_shape[0], tf.int64), dtype=ind.dtype),
                                        shape=tf.stack([input_shape[0], 1, 1, 1]))
        b = tf.ones_like(ind) * batch_range
        b = tf.reshape(b, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
        ind_ = tf.reshape(ind, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
        ind_ = tf.concat([b, ind_], 1)

        ret = tf.scatter_nd(ind_, pool_, shape=tf.cast(flat_output_shape, tf.int64))
        ret = tf.reshape(ret, tf.stack(output_shape))

        set_input_shape = pool.get_shape()
        set_output_shape = [set_input_shape[0], set_input_shape[1] * ksize[1], set_input_shape[2] * ksize[2], set_input_shape[3]]
        ret.set_shape(set_output_shape)
    return ret

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 4, 1])
    y, ind = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(
        x,
        ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
        padding='SAME'
    )

    z = unpool(y, ind)

    x_, y_, z_ = sess.run([x, y, z])
```

For batch size 1 it works OK, but for batch size > 1 it crashes with the next issue:

```
2018-09-22 16:33:57.010504: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-09-22 16:33:57.082638: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at scatter_nd_op.cc:119 : Invalid argument: Invalid indices: [2,0] = [1, 21] does not index into [4,16]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid indices: [2,0] = [1, 21] does not index into [4,16]
     [[Node: name/ScatterNd = ScatterNd[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](name/concat, name/Reshape, name/Cast_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tst.py", line 39, in <module>
    x_, y_, z_ = sess.run([x, y, z])
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid indices: [2,0] = [1, 21] does not index into [4,16]
     [[Node: name/ScatterNd = ScatterNd[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](name/concat, name/Reshape, name/Cast_1)]]

Caused by op 'name/ScatterNd', defined at:
  File "tst.py", line 37, in <module>
    z = unpool(y, ind)
  File "tst.py", line 20, in unpool
    ret = tf.scatter_nd(ind_, pool_, shape=tf.cast(flat_output_shape, tf.int64))
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6788, in scatter_nd
    "ScatterNd", indices=indices, updates=updates, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/vrudenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid indices: [2,0] = [1, 21] does not index into [4,16]
     [[Node: name/ScatterNd = ScatterNd[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](name/concat, name/Reshape, name/Cast_1)]]
```

Where could be a problem and how I can fix it?

Unpooling function was taken from [this issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169), but nothing is told about unpooling for batch there.

My `tf.__version__` is 1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tofik.AI witch Tensorflow version do you use?
According to the latest documentation, it's incorrect.
My implementation:

```
def unpool(pool, ind, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], name=None):
with tf.variable_scope('name') as scope:
    input_shape = tf.shape(pool)
    output_shape = [input_shape[0], input_shape[1] * ksize[1], input_shape[2] * ksize[2], input_shape[3]]

    flat_input_size = tf.cumprod(input_shape)[-1]
    flat_output_shape = tf.stack([output_shape[0], output_shape[1] * output_shape[2] * output_shape[3]])

    pool_ = tf.reshape(pool, tf.stack([flat_input_size]))
    batch_range = tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.cast(output_shape[0], tf.int64), dtype=ind.dtype),
                             shape=tf.stack([input_shape[0], 1, 1, 1]))
    b = tf.ones_like(ind) * batch_range
    b = tf.reshape(b, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
    ind_ = tf.reshape(ind, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
    ind_ = ind_ - b * tf.cast(flat_output_shape[1], tf.int64)
    ind_ = tf.concat([b, ind_], 1)

    ret = tf.scatter_nd(ind_, pool_, shape=tf.cast(flat_output_shape, tf.int64))
    ret = tf.reshape(ret, tf.stack(output_shape))

    set_input_shape = pool.get_shape()
    set_output_shape = [set_input_shape[0], set_input_shape[1] * ksize[1], set_input_shape[2] * ksize[2], set_input_shape[3]]
    ret.set_shape(set_output_shape)
return ret
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks. But what was the problem? Can you post a link to TF documentation, so that I'd got the idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a repository that implements the [unpool op in CUDA](https://github.com/mattangus/Tensorflow-Unpool-Op). The [`unpool_example.py`](https://github.com/mattangus/Tensorflow-Unpool-Op/blob/master/src/unpool_example.py) file shows how to use the library. From initial testing it is about two times faster than composing existing tensorflow functions at inference (4 times during training).

Just use it like the following:

```
import unpool

#pool, inds = max_pool_with_inds
unpool_layer = unpool.unpool(pool, inds,
                             output_size=[height, width],
                             name="unpool")
```

Full disclosure, I authored this repo.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def unpool(pool, ind, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], name=None):
    with tf.variable_scope('name') as scope:
        input_shape = tf.shape(pool)
        output_shape = [input_shape[0], input_shape[1] * ksize[1], input_shape[2] * ksize[2], input_shape[3]]

        flat_input_size = tf.cumprod(input_shape)[-1]
        flat_output_shape = tf.stack([output_shape[0], output_shape[1] * output_shape[2] * output_shape[3]])

        pool_ = tf.reshape(pool, tf.stack([flat_input_size]))
        batch_range = tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.cast(output_shape[0], tf.int64), dtype=ind.dtype),
                                        shape=tf.stack([input_shape[0], 1, 1, 1]))
        b = tf.ones_like(ind) * batch_range
        b = tf.reshape(b, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
        ind_ = tf.reshape(ind, tf.stack([flat_input_size, 1]))
        ind_ = tf.concat([b, ind_], 1)

        ret = tf.scatter_nd(ind_, pool_, shape=tf.cast(flat_output_shape, tf.int64))
        ret = tf.reshape(ret, tf.stack(output_shape))

        set_input_shape = pool.get_shape()
        set_output_shape = [set_input_shape[0], set_input_shape[1] * ksize[1], set_input_shape[2] * ksize[2], set_input_shape[3]]
        ret.set_shape(set_output_shape)
    return ret


batch_size=10
with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = tf.random_normal([batch_size,16,16,1])
    y, ind = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(
        x,
        ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
        padding='SAME'
    )

    z = unpool(y, ind)
    x_, y_, z_=sess.run([x, y, z])



aa=x_[4,:,:,0]
bb=y_[4,:,:,0]
cc=z_[4,:,:,0]
```

You may update the tensorflow.
I am using tensorflow 1.12.0